# Add images to slick from js

Tags: javascript, html, image, slick.js

I am using the slick of kenwheeler (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

When load pictures from DOM with file js external the slick dont create. If the image is in html page the slick works fine.

section of html page when load the slick

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="productosFavoritos" class="product-category-carousel mobile-special-arrows animated-arrows slick">
    </div>
</div>
```

The external file js to load slick with images from server

```
          ........
    cadena = cadena + "<div class='product-category hover-squared'></a>";
    cadena = cadena + "<a href='"+url+"'><img src='images/category-empty.png' data-lazy='"+imagen+"' alt='"+nombre+"'></a> ";
    cadena = cadena + "<div class='product-category__hover caption'></div>";
    cadena = cadena + "<div class='product-category__info'>";
    cadena = cadena + "<div class='product-category__info__ribbon'>";
    cadena = cadena + "<h5 class='product-category__info__ribbon__title'>men SUITS</h5>";
        cadena = cadena + "<div class='product-category__info__ribbon__count'>32 products</div>";
    cadena = cadena + "</div></div></div>";

    addImagenRollower(nombre);

    }

    if (Info != null && Info != "")
    {
      //Introducimos la informacion de los productos destacados en el contenido central.
                                    document.getElementById("productosFavoritos").innerHTML= cadena;    


       if (!window.jQuery) 
       {
        document.write('<script src="vendor/slick/slick.min.js"></script>');
       }

    }




    function addImagenRollower(nombre)
    {

        $j('.add-remove').slick('slickAdd','<div><h3>' + nombre + '</h3></div>');


    }
```

Show this

[slick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOLyq.jpg)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are invoking `addImagenRollower` which calls the `slick(...)` function before you load the slick.js.

Try to place this:

```
<script src="vendor/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

In the HTML directly (before your script) and then you can remove this from there:

```
if (!window.jQuery) 
{
 document.write('<script src="vendor/slick/slick.min.js"></script>');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, in In the HTML I have it also in html, but dont works.

Comment: @siemensgti try to use the debugger in the page (right-click+inspect), search where that line is placed and check if it appears before your code. Go also to the **NET** tab/panel and check if the slick.min.js was loaded properly. Finally go to the **Console** tab and type `$('#productosFavoritos').slick()` (if this doesn't override the content on that `div`, slick is not working properly).

Comment: sorry but i dont understand....the code for div is create  DOM, but if the code put in the HTML run ok, why? ... I desperate :(

Comment: @siemensgti usa el depurador (botón derecho del ratón + inspeccionar), busca donde está la línea del slick y si aparece antes de su código. Vaya también a la pestaña / panel de **red** y comproba si el slick.min.js se cargó correctamente. Finalmente, vaya a la pestaña de la consola y escribe `$('#productosFavoritos').slick()` (si esto no coloca el slider dentro del `div`, slick no está funcionando correctamente).